# Datagrid read Xml

Tags: c#, datagrid

myi am trying to read from an xml and show it in a Datagrid. here is my code inside my datagrid.

> string filePath = "xml path";
>
> dsAuthors.ReadXml(filePath);

```
       dataGrid1.DataSource = dsAuthors;
        dataGrid1.DataMember = "authors";
        dataGrid1.CaptionText = dataGrid1.DataMember;
```

it works fine but.. the

> dataGrid1.CaptionText = dataGrid1.DataMember;

says it doesent exist? can i please get some advice
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The CaptionText property was removed by microsoft because nobody used it in the past. So to answer your question the property does not exists. That's it.

see also: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/15fabc1f-51d9-4814-84b0-69c0a055c512/

Comment: it says to me that it cant find the .CaptionText "missing assembly maybe"?